# WPF library work with voice

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, audio, voice

Does anyone know WPF library work with voice.

Functionallity:

1. noise suppression
2. adjusting the sound quality
3. etc

Comment: **Close-Voting:** *Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.* - BTW, WPF is a UI Framework, it has nothing to do with what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start from here, maybe it help you http://naudio.codeplex.com/